# Purpose of opening and closing files python

Tags: python

What is the logic behind python requiring that a file be opened for write or append before being written to? Is there an advantage of doing this compared with something like bash which can just directly write to the file with something like: `print 'Hello World' >> output.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Bash command is actually a small script or program, it's supposed to provide end to end operations.

For programming, you'll use more basic unit operations (open, close, read, write, rewind, seek) than a set of operations (copy, delete). It's true both for `Python, C`, etc.

If you go deeper into operating system coding, you will probably need operations to manipulate file representation details such as file handler and storage system.

It's different level of abstraction for handle problems of different granularity.

Comment: sooo, what is the advantage of having a file object?

Comment: In Python? Generally, it adapts the IO model in UNIX or C programming design, either a FILE or PIPE or other devices such as web port is a stream. For streams you just need to open it, operate on it, then close it. The  operating system or language internal will help you handle the details (drivers, etc) for opening or closing it, leave you to simple interfaces and coding pattern.

Comment: For that you have more cryptic languages like perl, python's emphasis is on usability, I am guessing that's why.